# Set all varchar columns up to the same length in the dbt project models

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbt

I am using dbt to create models that contain multiple varchar columns.

Is there a way to limit the sizes of ALL the columns in those models to a specific length? To illustrate the question

1. Let's say that we have two source tables with the structure

table_a

| Column names | data types |
| --- | --- |
| column_a1 | int |
| column_a2 | varchar(1000) |
| column_a3 | varchar(700) |

table_b

| Column names | data types |
| --- | --- |
| column_b1 | int |
| column_b2 | varchar(10) |
| column_b3 | int |

Assume that my queries on the dbt project models are `SELECT * FROM table_a` and `SELECT * FROM table_b`. The goal is to have a configuration set on the project level (let's say on `dbt_project.yml` file) that will create the target models as below and truncate the content of the strings inside to 100 characters

model_a

| Column names | data types |
| --- | --- |
| column_a1 | int |
| column_a2 | varchar(100) |
| column_a3 | varchar(100) |

Please notice the size on the column_a1 and column_a2 are same and equal to 100, as per configuration, but column_b2 below would remain with the same size as the original table

model_b

| Column names | data types |
| --- | --- |
| column_b1 | int |
| column_b2 | varchar(10) |
| column_b3 | int |

That value of 100 should be set once on the project level or in a macro configuration

I have thought to do this functionality creating a macro, but I wonder if there is something like that already available. It could be a config on the `dbt_project.yml` or a macro to achieve the same

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!